# Yarn not found in Jhipster generated jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jhipster

I have used the latest JHipster 4 generator to create a simple (monolithic) app, selecting angular 2 and gradle as build system. Although JHipster is really awesome I get the following error when trying to run the generated build pipeline:

```
:npmInstall
> hippo-4@0.0.0 postinstall /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test-pipeline 
> yarn run webpack:build
sh: 1: yarn: not found
```

According to the documentation of the gradle-node-plugin a local installaion of yarn should be created by default. Any hints how I can get a working jenkins pipeline for JHipster using gradle?

Comment: I think you found a bug and should report it on github. Yarn should be installed under `.gradle/yarn/yarn`, I don't know why it is not picked up. gradle is not the favorite build tool used by JHipster users so it is less tested than maven.

Comment: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/5177